# how to remove extra space in paragraph (MS Office)

Tags: microsoft-word

When the new word doesn't fit in and start with a new line, the last word of the previous paragraph will be moved to the right? how can I correct it?

[image: first pic]

[image: second pic]

Comment: That's a risk when you full justify (both left and right).  The fill space to accomplish that needs to go somewhere.  An easy solution is to hyphenate the long word.  Pretty much anything else looks inconsistent.  You can shorten the gap some by adding a tiny amount to the spacing between letters on that line, but it will be noticeable if more than a tiny amount.

Comment: @fixer1234 so how can I turn off full justify?

Comment: I don't have ready access to Word, but it is typically one of three symbols in the tool ribbon (one for left, one for right, one for full), which graphically indicate the alignment.  It should also be in the menu in an obvious place like Formatting, and probably in the right-click menu for the paragraph.  You don't want to have everything full-justified except one paragraph, though; make it consistent.  You change it by selecting everything you want to change and picking a different alignment (typically Left).